# Ruby - more elegant pushing to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, append, each

```
valrow = [ 0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875]
lblrow = [48,  8539,  188,  8540, 189,  8541,  190,  8542]
opts = []
(0..7).each {|i| opts.push([lblrow[i].chr(Encoding::UTF_8), valrow[i]]) }
```

What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array#zip`

```
valrow = [ 0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875]
lblrow = [48,  8539,  188,  8540, 189,  8541,  190,  8542]
opts = lblrow.map { |c| c.chr(Encoding::UTF_8) }.zip(valrow)
```

Comment: please can you explain this ?

Comment: I cannot explain `Array#zip` better that [documentation do](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip). I hope that [`Array#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) is well known to you. I do not understand why have you down voted this, but there is your explanation.

Comment: The general rule here is that you should include in your answer your reasoning and not link to external sources that could change, this means your answer stands as a timestamped solution. The ruby docs are very terse on this and I don't feel they explained why zip was better.

Comment: `Array#zip` is better because it is small, simple, built in and directly show your goal to anyone who worked with any functionish language. Also, in theory (I do not have time to benchmark) using `Array#zip` allows interpreter to provide some optimalizations that would be much harder to detect in "normal" code. Also, if you find any other answer more readable then up vote them instead down voting answer that you think is "unreadable".

Comment: And about "The general rule here is that you should include in your answer your reasoning and not link to external sources that could change" I have linked to official documentation to exact version of language, so it cannot change, as Ruby 2.2.0 is now released and it's documentation is immutable since then.

Answer (score 1):

Or use `collect.with_index`:

```
valrow = [ 0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875]
lblrow = [48,  8539,  188,  8540, 189,  8541,  190,  8542]
opts = valrow.collect.with_index { |val,index| [lblrow[index].chr(Encoding::UTF_8), val] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [Enumerator](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator) object in this case:

```
value_enum = valrow.to_enum
opts = lblrow.map { |item| [item.chr(Encoding::UTF_8), value_enum.next] }
```